# How to create a List with children tree from SwiftData model

Tags: list, swiftui, children, swift-data

I'm trying to store this model using `SwiftData` in order to display it within `List` with children tree.

However `List` requires its children to be of the same type as the parent and that's an issue for `SwiftData` as it seems. Immediately after I build and run following code I get an "Unknown related type error" fatal within the model macro.

Model:

```
@Model final class LibraryItem: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) let id: UUID
    var name: String
    ...
    var subMenuItems: [LibraryItem]?
}
```

Error:

[image]

I build the tree using a few recursive functions to reflect the file system hierarchy of given URL. This is my `List`:

```
List(
    libraryItems,
    children: \.subMenuItems,
    selection: Binding(
        get: {
            selectedLibraryItemId
        },
        set: { ids, _ in
            selectionHandler(ids)
        }
    )
) { item in
    Text(item.name)
}
```

And this is how I initialise the `ModelContainer`:

```
init() {
    let schema = Schema([LibraryItem.self])
    let config = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, groupContainer: .identifier("antonincharvat.com.appName"))
        
    do {
        let container = try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: config)
        self.libraryItemsModelContainer = container
    } catch {
        fatalError("Couldn't create ModelContainer")
    }
}
```

Is there any way for this to work? I tried to use computed property as the children collection, but `List` initialises all its children at once causing this approach unusable.

Comment: this looks similar to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77588052/crash-when-decoding-json-using-swiftdata-model-with-recursive-relationship  I tried a few things to make recursion such as this work in SwiftData, but did not succeed.

Comment: How do you build up your tree?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I updated the question with more information regarding the tree generation.

Comment: Sorry, I meant how you built the tree of model objects (LibraryItem). How you create, combine and store the objects.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Well I would generate the array of LibraryItem using the above-mentioned recursive function and then insert each object into the `ModelContext` using `insert(model:)` function, but since the app is terminated right after the start, I never get to this point.

Comment: Ok, I tried to reproduce but I failed until I had create some LibraryItem items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I see it there are two things you need to change in your model to make this work, create a second property for the inverse of the relationship and also use the `@Relationship` wrapper for one of the relationship properties to exclusively point out what the key path is to the opposite property of the relationship.

This is what my `LibraryItem` model ended up like

```
@Model final class LibraryItem: Identifiable {
    @Attribute(.unique) let id: UUID
    var name: String
    var subMenuItems: [LibraryItem]?

    @Relationship(deleteRule: .nullify, inverse: \LibraryItem.subMenuItems)
    var parentItem: LibraryItem?

    init(name: String) {
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
    }
}
```