# Can CloudKit or SwiftData store tree-structured data?

Tags: swift, swift-data

I want to store data like this, but only got crashes.

```
@Model
final class Node: Identifiable, Hashable {
  var id: String?
  var name: String = ""
  var parrent: Node?
  var children: [Node]?
  
  init(
    id: String? = UUID().uuidString,
    name: String
  ) {
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
  }
}
```

Can CloudKit or SwiftData store tree-structured data?
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: As a first step add the `@Relationship` wrapper to one of the properties to point out which one is the inverse property to see if that helps.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77625612/9223839